# Does 'Select' always order by primary key?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, primary-key

A basic simple question for all of you DBA.

When I do a select, is it always guaranteed that my result will be ordered by the primary key, or should I specify it with an 'order by'?

I'm using Oracle as my DB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is MySQL row order for "SELECT \* FROM table\_name;"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949641/what-is-mysql-row-order-for-select-from-table-name)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

No, if you do not use "order by" you are not guaranteed any ordering whatsoever. In fact, you are not guaranteed that the ordering from one query to the next will be the same. Remember that SQL is dealing with data in a set based fashion. Now, one database implementation or another may happen to provide orderings in a certain way but you should never rely on that.

Comment: Any chance the records will be returned in the order of the clustered index?

Comment: A very good chance, but not guaranteed.  Complicated queries involving joins, views, sub queries, and the like can leave the result set ordered very differently.

Comment: ANd it may return sometimes inthe clustered index order and sometimes not. Always use an order by if you want a specific order.

Comment: "Any chance?" Yes, somewhere between 0 and 100%, a range large enough that you shouldn't rely on it. Use standard SQL syntax and behavior as much as possible, it eases the task of moving between and/or supporting multiple DBMS vendors greatly (I'm not saying don't optimize for a specific vendor, just do go mad about it - use some common sense, no matter how uncommon it seems to be :-).

Comment: I've inherited software that would fail if Oracle returned data not ordered by primary key, and it never did.  Of course that was bad software, just mentioning it because Oracle seems very consistent.

Answer (score 7):

> When I do a select, is it always guaranteed that my result will be ordered by the primary key, or should I specify it with an 'order by'?

No, it's by far not guaranteed.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table
```

most probably will use `TABLE SCAN` which does not use primary key at all.

You can use a hint:

```
SELECT  /*+ INDEX(pk_index_name) */
        *
FROM    table
```

, but even in this case the ordering is not guaranteed: if you use `Enterprise Edition`, the query may be parallelized.

This is a problem, since `ORDER BY` cannot be used in a `SELECT` clause subquery and you cannot write something like this:

```
SELECT  (
        SELECT  column
        FROM    table
        WHERE   rownum = 1
        ORDER BY
                other_column
        )
FROM    other_table
```

Comment: Not a problem: SELECT DISTINCT FIRST_VALUE(column) OVER (ORDER BY other_column) FROM table;

Comment: @Jeffrey: it's possible, but the subquery will select all FIRST_VALUE's and HASH UNIQUE them. This will kill all performance it the subquery returns lots of rows.

Answer (score 3):

No, ordering is never guaranteed unless you use an ORDER BY.

The order that rows are fetched is dependent on the access method (e.g. full table scan, index scan), the physical attributes of the table, the logical location of each row within the table, and other factors.  These can all change even if you don't change your query, so in order to guarantee a consistent ordering in your result set, ORDER BY is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your DB and also it depends on indexed fields.

For example, in my table Users every user has unique varchar(20) field - login, and primary key - id.

And "Select * from users" returns rowset ordered by login.

Answer (score 0):

If you desire specific ordering then declare it specifically using ORDER BY.

What if the table doesn't have primary key?

Comment: If the table doesn't have a primary key, you have other problems than the order in which the data is returned.

Comment: totally, but it doesn't stop people from designing tables badly!

Answer (score 0):

If you want your results in a specific order, always specify an order by