# How to Sort Ascending Without "ORDER BY " in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Nice to Meet you

Another program is using that SQL to load data,
But DB Server more than 1TB.

Last SQL sentence use to " ORDER BY"  loading time is too long
How To sort in ascending order by timestamp without "ORDER BY" in SQL?

```
SELECT timestamp
, node
, effect_ion
, effect_value
, priority

FROM   "--(*vendor(PML),product(LogServer) Global Event Log @Global *)--"

WHERE   (timestamp >= DATEADD(DD,-6,GETDATE()))
And
(priority BETWEEN  '253' AND '255')


ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

Comment: Please, add your DBMS tag.

Comment: `GETDATE()` <-- clearly SQL Server

Comment: What you need is a CLUSTERED INDEX on your table for timestamp column

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, but nevertheless OP should follow "good" pattern in answering SQL questions, especially on optimization topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked:

> How To sort in ascending order by timestamp without "ORDER BY" in SQL?

You don't.  But, you can try adding the following index, which, if used, might let SQL do the `ORDER BY` sort much faster:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON yourTable (priority, timestamp);
```

Comment: For which database? In Oracle it will not be used.

Comment: @astentx The syntax used by the OP is clearly SQL Server.   As to whether it would use this index, that would depend on the data and a few other things.  Certainly, there are databases out there which could use this index.

Comment: OP is new to indexing and your answer should be more detailed and if possible should have some reference links.

Comment: @Singh No, doing a full background explanation on how indexing works is too broad, and, if my answer really needed that, then the question should probably be closed as too broad.

Comment: Agreed that there is no single holy grail that can cover everything about indexes but still it will be better if you could have a brief explanation and some keywords like INDEX, CLUSTERED and etc and at least a ref link from where the OP can start to explore the indexes.

Comment: Even I'm fairly new to indexes but as a beginner, I can suggest that these type of things in an answer helps a lot.

Answer (score -2):

[CLUSTER INDEXES](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-indexes/sql-server-clustered-indexes/): A clustered index defines the order in which data is physically stored in a table.

So using this you can define the order by which the data will be stored, based on a particular column.

By default, the PRIMARY KEY creates an INDEX which causes the data to be stored in ASC order of Id (PK) column. But as it turns out this will NOT guarantee any sort order (reference links in comments).

[MS DOC for creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/create-clustered-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX <index_name>
ON <table_name>(<column_name> ASC/DESC)
```

In order to check the INDEXES for a table you can use

```
EXEC sp_helpindex table_name
```

PS: Please read more/discuss with someone in your team before creating INDEXES as it affects the performance of the queries.

Comment: A clustered index will **NOT** guarantee any sort order.

Comment: As far as I know (which is not that far) the table can have at max a single clustered index and 'A clustered index defines the order in which data is physically stored in a table.' If ^ the information is incorrect, can you tell the reason why it won't GUARANTEE sorting.

Comment: The **only** way to _guarantee_ a specific sort order is to use `ORDER BY`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1110365)  or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824855/does-select-always-order-by-primary-key) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20050403)

Comment: @Singh, here's more info in why [ORDER BY is required](https://www.dbdelta.com/order-by-is-required/).

Comment: Answers, like questions, should still be useful and relevant if any links go dead. This is one reason why link-only posts are highly discouraged. In addition, an answer should make an attempt to explain why the content addresses the OP's question. Perhaps focus on your own answer first.