# How to insert data in a table in SQL in sequence

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

Consider this code:

```
public void Insertindb(int chnlNm, string Date, string Time, string Progname)
{
    DbConnection db = new DbConnection();
    db.connectionOpen();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.SchedulProgram (ChannelNumber,Date,Time,ProgramName) VALUES(@chnlNm,@date,@time,@progname)", db.con);

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@chnlNm", chnlNm));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@date",Date));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@time", Time));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@progname", Progname));
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}",chnlNm,Date,Time,Progname);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    db.connectionClose();
}
```

I use this code to insert data in a table. It inserts data in a table. When I call the function multiple times,

```
sdb.Insertindb(channelno, date, time, programname)
```

It randomly inserts data in the table not in sequence. I want it to insert data in sequence. How is it possible?

Comment: Insert in sequence ?? what sequence?..

Comment: row insert after last inserted row.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "sequence" inside a database. "Sequences" are defined upon SELECTing

Comment: Tables in SQL are *unordered* collections of rows. They have no inherent ordering. The only thing that determines the order that rows are returned in, for any particular query, is the `ORDER BY` clause that is applied to *that* query.

Comment: how to use order by with insert query

Comment: You **don't**. As I say, tables have *no order*. So `ORDER BY` in an `INSERT` makes **no** sense.

Comment: means data insert randomly and when i want to use data,can use order By clause

Comment: it doesn't insert data randomly, it inserts data in order you gave him .

Comment: Actually, there is a physical order determined by the CLUSTERED INDEX

Comment: How are you viewing the data after insert? Via a select statement? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824855/does-select-always-order-by-primary-key

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the commenters says that there is no "sequence" or "order" in the data.
Yes, there IS a physical order in the tables, and its defined by the [CLUSTERED INDEX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933131%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) of the table.

A clustered index determines the physical order of data in a table.

Check this fiddle:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d7e14/2

Comment: The clustered index does exist, yes, but it does **not** guarantee anything about the order in which rows are returned from a table. On *small* tables, and performing single queries, the results will *usually* be returned in the clustered index order, but that is by no means guaranteed - without an `ORDER BY` clause, the system is free to return rows in whatever order is most convenient.

Comment: See e.g. [this article](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/hugo_kornelis/archive/2006/12/31/Beatles-vs-Stones.aspx) for a demonstration where the results (without an `ORDER BY`) are returned in an order different to the clustered index order.

Answer (score 0):

since your inserting the date and time, is that the order of what your refer to as 'row after row'?

if so, the simple solution would be to select ordered by those columns?

```
select chnlNm, Date, Time, Progname from dbo.SchedulProgram order by date, time
```