# Difference in users listing on localhost and heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, railstutorial.org

I just finished railstutorial by michael hartl lesson 9. 
On localhost everything looks fine, but when i deploy application on heroku some users are on wrong places in user's list (for example, Example User have to be at first page, but it's at second page). Why does it happen?

My appliction: https://mordor-depth.herokuapp.com/users

You can sing-in with Example User:
example@railstutorial.org
foobar

Sorry, for a stupid question:)

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:index,:edit,:update,:destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user, only: :destroy
  def index
    @users=User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

    def show
    @user=User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user=User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success]="Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
        render 'new'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success]='User deleted!'
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  def admin_user
    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
  end

  def edit

  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private
    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:name,:email,:password,:password_confirmation)
    end

    #Before filters
    def signed_in_user
      store_location
      redirect_to signin_url, notice:'Please sign in.' unless signed_in?
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'All users') %>
<h1>All users</h1>
<%= will_paginate %>

<ul class="users">
  <%= render @users %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

_user.html.erb

```
<li>
    <%= gravatar_for user, size:52 %>
    <%=link_to user.name, user %>
    <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user)%>
        | <%= link_to "delete", user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
    <% end %>
</li>
```

Comment: Can you update the question with the code you have on the Users controller? I'm interesting in seeing the code for the action being executed and the view, so it should be app/controllers/users.rb action index, and app/views/users/index.html.erb

Comment: Done. I've thought, that code can be seen in railstutorial... I think, that it's everything ok with code(on local app works fine) and it must be some database issues on heroku.

Comment: @nuT707 you are not ordering the records in index action of your controller so what makes you think that Example User should come on first page and not on second?

Comment: @KirtiThorat on localhost it orders by index, and and on heroku it looks the same, only example user is in wrong place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see on the index action that you are not doing any ordering:

```
def index
  @users=User.paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

you can easily order by name doing

```
def index
  @users = User.order(:name).paginate(page: params[:page])
end
```

Comment: Thank u, but it's still interesring for me why on local list is sorted  by id, but on production no?

Comment: +1 This is what I was talking about. You need to order the records if you want to see them in a particular order. Regarding sorting by id confusion you can look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824855/does-select-always-order-by-primary-key might resolve your doubts.

Comment: When you don't specify any sort, the records order depends on the database engine, and because your database engine is not the same than the database engine of heroku, there you have the difference. If you want to order by id, just use **.order(:id)**